# How to prevent seeing image from browser but allow on desktop app

Tags: c++, qt, web

I'm developing a desktop app connected to a website. I store the user profile images in the file system of a web server so I can reach them from the URL, the problem is that I don't want that someone can access the images from any web browser like chrome.

Is there a way in which I can access the images through the URL and display them in my desktop app (built with qt) but also prevent accessing these images from a regular web browser.

The desktop app user is incapable of seeing the URL from the image tough.

Comment: It's a strange thing to request ("how can I provide information but not provide information?") but you could discourage cursory discovery by denying access based on `User-Agent` string (not secure; easily changed by users) or by using one of the standard HTTP Authorization schemes.  What you want is effectively a form of DRM, which is known to be a Hard Problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to handle with small webpage in your webserver.

Request the web page for image.

While requesting send `User-Agent` information to the webpage.

Based on the `User-Agent` you can send the response back from webpage.

**Consider below example:**

```
QNetworkRequest request; 
request.setUrl(QUrl("YOUR IMAGE URL"));
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "YOUR APP NAME/1.0");
```

In the webpage validate "YOUR APP NAME" and send valid response.

use `QNetworkReply` to get the response.

In this way the you can completely shield your images directory in web server.

Comment: This "protection" fails when using a web browser that allows the `User-Agent` to be set in the browser's configuration.

Comment: It seems secure enough for me, I know that someone can change the user agent of their site but giving a custom user agent name is like guessing a password. Anyway I would appreciate if you could ellaborate a bit more how the web part should work, I don't understand the web part structure.

Comment: A simple web application something like jsp or asp or any other language, with just one server side scripting file to validate your request and send the image as response. You will be calling this application's URL for retrieving the image.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can encrypt image , so that only you (your application) can see the decryption key. after geting encrypted image, decrypt it and show. in this case even if someone get the image, hi/she will get only encrypted content
2. You can do basic authorization of image request(send some secret token in url and compare it on back end)